# Is there a way to see all my awarded badges on all sites?

Tags: support, badges

Each individual site provides a list of badges I've been awarded, but is there a way to see the results for all sites at the same time?

This is really an X/Y question.  What I was originally trying to do is to see if I failed to take the tour [("Informed" badge)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/194/informed) on any site that I'm a member of.

Comment: Why is this important? I mean, remember that badges and reputation are artificial gamification; don't give them _too_ much importance. Next time you want to ask or answer something on a site you're not a regular of - check out the site-specific parts of the tour.

Comment: @einpoklum-reinstateMonica, It *isn't* important. I know badges don't really matter (beyond the 200 that makes it appear in the graphs, I don't even care much about reputation points).  And this question itself is not important.  But I'm anal retentive, which makes me aware of the totally useless fact that I *might* have missed a tour.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Begin this year, I wrote a [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/962580/of-a-specific-badge-for-a-single-user-networkwide?badgename=Informed&AccountID=6085540) for a similar purpose to your 'Y'. It includes child metas too, on which you can't earn the Informed badge, so it's not ideal for this purpose.

I thought I had a version specifically for this badge, including a direct link to the Tour on the specific site, but I failed to find it (SEDE doesn't offer much functionality to search in queries). No problem, [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1159324/missing-informed-badges?AccountID=12266974) you can see which links you should click. It only lists sites you're actually a member of; [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/628471/sites-where-a-user-doesnt-have-an-account-on) is a query which produces a list of sites you need to join.

(Please remember that SEDE is updated once a week, on Sunday morning.)

Comment: That worked great, especially with the built-in links to the sites.  Several "Meta" sites appear not to have tours.  Is that correct? (If so your search could be improved by not including sites that don't award the specific badge.  But please don't waste your time on it.)

Comment: [This link](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1159324/missing-informed-badges?AccountID=12266974) (the second one in my answer) skips Meta sites and links directly to the Tour and directly helps you with your 'X'.